# Displaying a broom::tidy tibble as a printed summary table

Tags: r, lm, broom

I have what may seem like a strange question (but details of why I'm asking
will become clear soon).

Consider fitting a linear model in `R`, as follows:

`lm_fit <- lm(mpg ~ cyl+disp, data = mtcars)`.

Now suppose we produce a tidy `tibble` (named `out_summ`) of the
summary of our fit using the amazing `broom` package as follows:

```r
out_summ <- broom::tidy(lm_fit)
out_summ
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>   term        estimate std.error statistic  p.value
#>   <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 (Intercept)  34.7       2.55       13.6  4.02e-14
#> 2 cyl          -1.59      0.712      -2.23 3.37e- 2
#> 3 disp         -0.0206    0.0103     -2.01 5.42e- 2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Now consider just printing the summary of the `lm_fit` object
to the console as follows:

```r
summary(lm_fit)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = mpg ~ cyl + disp, data = mtcars)
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
#> -4.4213 -2.1722 -0.6362  1.1899  7.0516 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> (Intercept) 34.66099    2.54700  13.609 4.02e-14 ***
#> cyl         -1.58728    0.71184  -2.230   0.0337 *  
#> disp        -0.02058    0.01026  -2.007   0.0542 .  
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 3.055 on 29 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.7596, Adjusted R-squared:  0.743 
#> F-statistic: 45.81 on 2 and 29 DF,  p-value: 1.058e-09
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Now, my question is given the `lm_fit` object and the tidy `out_summ` tibble
as **inputs**, is it possible write a function to easily reproduce the
printed `summary(lm_fit)` table shown above?

I looked at the `getAnywhere(print.summary.lm)` for the `lm` summary function
and it is quite complicated.
In the sense that it sources individual columns and manually
adjusts spacing using `cat()` to pretty print. As such given the tidy tibbles,
can this be easily reverse engineered?

**Motivation:** I'm developing a statistical modeling object similar to `lm`,
however we are using tidy `tibble` formats from the start. We would still like
to add a summary method to our object. This would take our tidy `tibble` format
and print it out using the format of the `summary(lm_fit)` output style
above. That is, we don't want to just print the tibble, without first making
it look like the classical summary table format.

Any help on achieving this, with hopefully minimal code (given the tidy input),
would be appreciated.

Comment: The source code for summary.lm (line 261: https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/master/src/library/stats/R/lm.R) shows you can generate all required output for your summary table from just the lm.fit object (i.e. you don't need the tibble to create your output). Is there a reason you can't adapt this code to suit your 'lm-like' object?

Comment: @jared_mamrot - thanks. As mentioned in my code above, what you have linked to is the same code as `getAnywhere(print.summary.lm)` I mentioned above. I'm using `lm` as an analogy here. Basically in the new statistical modeling object that I've created (like `lm`, but different) all of my output is in already in tidy tibble format. I want to now also have a summary looking table for my new object. But I already have a tibble. So the situation is like reverse engineering `lm` summary using the tidy tibble output from an `lm` object. I would then apply this code to my setting. Does that clarify?

Comment: So my question is, how can we easily go from a `tibble` to the `print.summary.lm` source code you have pointed to using the manual and complicated nested `cat()` statements? As you can see the script is very manually constructed. I'm asking if there is an elegant way to get this summary table directly from the `tibble` output, in a much cleaner way (with correct column spacing etc). If it helps, as a thought experiment, just assume `lm` was written with `broom::tidy` summary attributes. And someone asks to produce the summary output for `lm` using this tidy output, how would you do it?

Comment: Ahh - that makes more sense - I'll look into it

Comment: thanks for your interest @jared_mamrot. I should clarify - I'm most interested in pretty printing the coefficients part of the summary output (which is what `broom::tidy` gives you), but the rest of the table would be nice to see constructed as well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how to fill in the rest of the summary table without using the lm_fit object (or equivalent), but maybe these 'first steps' will help.

```r
library(tidyverse)

lm_fit <- lm(mpg ~ cyl+disp, data = mtcars)

summarise_lm_like_object <- function(lm_fit){
  out_summ <- broom::tidy(lm_fit) %>%
    mutate(sig = ifelse(p.value <= 0.001, "***",
                        ifelse(p.value <= 0.01, "**",
                               ifelse(p.value <= 0.05, "*", ".")))) %>% 
    rename("Estimate" = estimate,
           "Std. Error" = std.error,
           "t value" = statistic,
           "Pr(>|t|)" = p.value,
           "Significance" = sig)
  
  print.data.frame(out_summ, row.names = FALSE)
  cat("---\n")
  cat("Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1")
}

summarise_lm_like_object(lm_fit)
#>         term    Estimate Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|) Significance
#>  (Intercept) 34.66099474 2.54700388 13.608536 4.022869e-14          ***
#>          cyl -1.58727681 0.71184427 -2.229809 3.366495e-02            *
#>         disp -0.02058363 0.01025748 -2.006696 5.418572e-02            .
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: this is fantastic! I think the main function here is `print.data.frame` which does a lot of the heavy print lifting of tibble to nice summary output. This was the main function I didn't want to manually implement. Thank you for sharing this code. Much appreciated!

Comment: It sounded like that was what you were trying to do - you're very welcome - good question